# Watson Discovery service getting error when i train the data

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

I have a data collection in Watson discovery service.
So i trained this data collection using postman request. 
After send request i checked in dashboard. 
It showing "**Rated with an incompatible scale**" and top of the dashboard showing "**This collection was previously trained using an incompatible scale. To fix this, either delete that training using the API and restart here; or update each rating below**" notifications. 
Can you explain why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The tooling uses 10 for relevant and 0 for irrelevant, and does not have an option for sort of relevant.

I suspect that you used 0,1,2 or a similar scale for your training

Through Postman you can check the status of the collection to see whether it has trained correctly or not : https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#list-collection-details